# Where one can get a prebuild blockscout database?

Tags: transactions, history, blockscout

To build a [blockscout](https://blockscout.github.io/blockscout-db-schema/tables/address_current_token_balances.html) database on requiers to have [a lot of space](https://docs.blockscout.com/for-developers/manual-deployment) (a [full archive node](https://docs.blockscout.com/for-developers/information-and-settings/requirements)). I want to continue building blockscout DB from some point in time (not from scratch) to shorten the amount of drive space my node has to offer. Is it possible - are there rebuild blockscout database images from where one can start from?

Answer (score 1):

You can run archive node in a hybrid mode: fast sync first and then switch to the archive mode. Find a minimal block number where archive state exist on your archive node, and you can set it for the next environment varaibles supported by Blockscout:

- `FIRST_BLOCK`

> The block number, where import of blocks by catchup fetcher begins from.

- `TRACE_FIRST_BLOCK`

> The block number, where indexing of internal transactions begins from.

This will allow to  start sync in Blockscout from the given block. But keep in mind, that if some address gained tokens before that given block and no more transactions with this token on the address after this block - the tokens will be invisible in Blockscout.

[This is the reference](https://docs.blockscout.com/for-developers/information-and-settings/env-variables) to the list of all supported Blockscout environment variables.